# How do I display Logut button once I login to the main UI?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement this feature in my React JS app where if I login successfully, the UI would display the Logout button in the navbar. But if I click on the Logout, I would be logged out from the main UI and redirected to the Login Page where the navbar won't have any Logout Button. Currently, when I log in to the main UI successfully, then I have to refresh the browser tab to show the logout button. It does not appear automatically once I log in successfully.

This is my header Component:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthenticationService from "../Login/AuthenticationService";

class HeaderComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const isUserLoggedIn = sessionStorage.getItem("authenticatedUser");
    console.log(isUserLoggedIn);

    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg ">
        <Router>
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <span className="header-title">TODO APP</span>
            </a>

            <ul className="navbar-nav d-flex flex-row ms-auto me-3">
              {isUserLoggedIn && (
                <Link
                  to="/login"
                  onClick={() => {
                    window.location.href = "/login";
                  }}
                >
                  {"  "}
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-success logout-button"
                    onClick={AuthenticationService.logout}
                  >
                    Logout
                  </button>
                </Link>
              )}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </Router>
        {"  "}
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default HeaderComponent;
```

The isUserLoggedIn is a boolean value that is retrieved from the session storage. If isUserLoggedIn is true then the Logout button would be displayed on the Navbar.

```js
const isUserLoggedIn = sessionStorage.getItem("authenticatedUser");
```

The AuthenticationService.js file is:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class AuthenticationService extends Component {
  registerSuccessfulLogin(username, password) {
    console.log("Login Successful");

    sessionStorage.setItem("authenticatedUser", username);
    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("authenticatedUser"));
  }

  isUserLoggedIn() {
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem("authenticatedUser");

    if (user === null) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }

    // return true;
  }
  logout() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem("authenticatedUser");
  }
  getLoggedInUserName() {
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem("authenticatedUser");
    if (user === null) return "";
    return user;
  }
}

export default new AuthenticationService();
```

The App.js component is:

```js
import "./App.css";
import DropDownMenu from "./components/DropdownMenu/DropDownMenu";
import HeaderComponent from "./components/Header/HeaderComponent";
import LoginComponent from "./components/Login/LoginComponent";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  useParams,
  Link,
} from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";
import "./loginStyle.css";
import "./Header.css";
import ErrorComponent from "./components/search-options/ErrorComponent";
import AuthenticatedRoute from "./components/DropdownMenu/AuthenticatedRoute";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HeaderComponent />

      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<LoginComponent />}></Route>
          {/* <Route path="/login" element={<Navigate to="/LoginComponent" />} /> */}
          <Route path="/login" default element={<LoginComponent />}></Route>

          <Route
            path="/pst"
            element={
              <AuthenticatedRoute>
                <DropDownMenu />
              </AuthenticatedRoute>
            }
          ></Route>
          <Route path="*" element={<ErrorComponent />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am not sure why do I have to refresh the Tab to show the Logout button on to the NavBar.

**EDIT**

I have added the Login component for further reference:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { data } from "jquery";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
import App from "../../App";
import HeaderComponent from "../Header/HeaderComponent";
import GetUserIp from "../tracking/GetUserIp";
import TrackLoginActivity from "../tracking/TrackLoginActivity";
import AuthenticationService from "./AuthenticationService";

class LoginComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      ipAddress: "",
      hasLoginFailed: false,
      isUserLoggedIn: false,
    };
    this.handleCredentialChange = this.handleCredentialChange.bind(this);
    this.submitLogin = this.submitLogin.bind(this);
  }

  handleCredentialChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.name);
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  submitLogin(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var session_url =
      "login check api url";

    GetUserIp.retrieveIpAddress().then((response) => {
      this.setState({ ipAddress: response.data.ip });
    });

    console.log(this.state.ipAddress);

    axios
      .post(
        session_url,
        {},
        {
          auth: {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password,
          },
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Authenticated");
        console.log(this.props);
        AuthenticationService.registerSuccessfulLogin(
          this.state.username,
          this.state.password
        );
        this.props.navigate(`/pst`);

        //track user login activity into the DB Entity, smart_tool_login_logs
        TrackLoginActivity.trackSuccessfulLogin(
          this.state.username,
          this.state.ipAddress
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error on autheication");
        this.setState({ hasLoginFailed: true });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="login-app">
        <form action="" className="login-form" onSubmit={this.submitLogin}>
          <div className="container">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="username"
              name="username"
              className="username-value"
              maxLength={30}
              autoComplete="on"
              value={this.state.username}
              onChange={this.handleCredentialChange}
            />

            <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="password"
              name="password"
              className="password-value"
              maxLength={30}
              autoComplete="on"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.handleCredentialChange}
            />

            {this.state.hasLoginFailed && (
              <div className="login-fail-message">
                Invalid username/password
              </div>
            )}
            <div className="login-btn"></div>
            <button className="btn btn-success login-btn" type="submit">
              Login
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function WithNavigate(props) {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  return <LoginComponent {...props} navigate={navigate} />;
}

export default WithNavigate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your header component is a stateless component, it has neither props nor internal state, so it is only rendered once with the initial value of `isUserLoggedIn`.

If you want the header component to react to the login status, it needs to be notified in some way that the value has changed. The easiest way to do so is to store this information in the state of your `App` component, then passing it down as a prop to the `HeaderComponent`.

```js
// App.js

import "./App.css";
import DropDownMenu from "./components/DropdownMenu/DropDownMenu";
import HeaderComponent from "./components/Header/HeaderComponent";
import LoginComponent from "./components/Login/LoginComponent";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  useParams,
  Link,
} from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";
import "./loginStyle.css";
import "./Header.css";
import ErrorComponent from "./components/search-options/ErrorComponent";
import AuthenticatedRoute from "./components/DropdownMenu/AuthenticatedRoute";
import AuthenticationService from "../Login/AuthenticationService";

function App() {
  const [isUserLoggedIn, setIsUserLoggedIn] = useState(AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn()) // use the session storage to get the initial state's value

  function onLoginSuccessful() {
    setIsUserLoggedIn(true); // update the state to notify React the value has changed
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HeaderComponent isUserLoggedIn={isUserLoggedIn} /> {/* pass down the state value as a prop */}

      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<LoginComponent onLoginSuccessful={onLoginSuccessful}/>}></Route>
          {/* <Route path="/login" element={<Navigate to="/LoginComponent" />} /> */}
          <Route path="/login" default element={<LoginComponent onLoginSuccessful={onLoginSuccessful} />}></Route>

          <Route
            path="/pst"
            element={
              <AuthenticatedRoute>
                <DropDownMenu />
              </AuthenticatedRoute>
            }
          ></Route>
          <Route path="*" element={<ErrorComponent />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
// HeaderComponent.js

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthenticationService from "../Login/AuthenticationService";

class HeaderComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const isUserLoggedIn = this.props.isUserLoggedIn; // retrieve the value from the props
    console.log(isUserLoggedIn);

    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg ">
        <Router>
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <span className="header-title">TODO APP</span>
            </a>

            <ul className="navbar-nav d-flex flex-row ms-auto me-3">
              {isUserLoggedIn && (
                <Link
                  to="/login"
                  onClick={() => {
                    window.location.href = "/login";
                  }}
                >
                  {"  "}
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-success logout-button"
                    onClick={AuthenticationService.logout}
                  >
                    Logout
                  </button>
                </Link>
              )}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </Router>
        {"  "}
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default HeaderComponent;
```

Note that you also have to pass a callback to `LoginComponent` to be called once the user successfully logs in. Using state updates, React gets notified that the value of `isUserLoggedIn` has changed and will re-render the components that depend on this value, including `HeaderComponent`.

**EDIT**: I updated the implementation of LoginComponent with the callback I mentionned

```js
// LoginComponent.js

import axios from "axios";
import { data } from "jquery";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
import App from "../../App";
import HeaderComponent from "../Header/HeaderComponent";
import GetUserIp from "../tracking/GetUserIp";
import TrackLoginActivity from "../tracking/TrackLoginActivity";
import AuthenticationService from "./AuthenticationService";

class LoginComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      ipAddress: "",
      hasLoginFailed: false,
      isUserLoggedIn: false,
    };
    this.handleCredentialChange = this.handleCredentialChange.bind(this);
    this.submitLogin = this.submitLogin.bind(this);
  }

  handleCredentialChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.name);
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  submitLogin(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var session_url =
      "login check api url";

    GetUserIp.retrieveIpAddress().then((response) => {
      this.setState({ ipAddress: response.data.ip });
    });

    console.log(this.state.ipAddress);

    axios
      .post(
        session_url,
        {},
        {
          auth: {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password,
          },
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Authenticated");
        console.log(this.props);
        AuthenticationService.registerSuccessfulLogin(
          this.state.username,
          this.state.password
        );

        // add this line to your `LoginComponent` so that
        // onLoginSuccessul is called when user is logged in

        this.props.onLoginSuccessful();

        this.props.navigate(`/pst`);

        //track user login activity into the DB Entity, smart_tool_login_logs
        TrackLoginActivity.trackSuccessfulLogin(
          this.state.username,
          this.state.ipAddress
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error on autheication");
        this.setState({ hasLoginFailed: true });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="login-app">
        <form action="" className="login-form" onSubmit={this.submitLogin}>
          <div className="container">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="username"
              name="username"
              className="username-value"
              maxLength={30}
              autoComplete="on"
              value={this.state.username}
              onChange={this.handleCredentialChange}
            />

            <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="password"
              name="password"
              className="password-value"
              maxLength={30}
              autoComplete="on"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.handleCredentialChange}
            />

            {this.state.hasLoginFailed && (
              <div className="login-fail-message">
                Invalid username/password
              </div>
            )}
            <div className="login-btn"></div>
            <button className="btn btn-success login-btn" type="submit">
              Login
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function WithNavigate(props) {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  return <LoginComponent {...props} navigate={navigate} />;
}

export default WithNavigate;
```

Comment: thank you for the solution, can you please elaborate on how do I pass a callback function onto my Login Component? I have added the code for LoginComponent for reference. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if you miss something